# CMS for DJ website

Tags: php, web, content-management-system, recommendation-engine

I am in the process of building a website for a DJ. Instead of reinventing the wheel, I thought I would look out there if there are any solution available. My requirements are:

- Ability to have own domain name & custom design
- Section for listening to DJ's song
- Section for photos
- Section for videos
- Usual CMS functionalities for managing static pages (personal bio)
- Self-hosted & PHP is a big plus
- Open source/proprietary free/paid doesn't matter

If you answer with a more generic CMS (i.e. WordPress), could you point out some extensions that would be helpful. I'm also open to web apps that don't fill every requirement, but explicit which of the requirements are not available.

Answer (score 2):

Not a 100% match for a DJ, but [Indexhibit](http://www.indexhibit.org/) is very popular among artists in general. I like it personally, and use it whenever I need to set up a simple, minimalistic CMS for a client.

It brings a lot of gallery and image management functions and is relatively easy to extend  if you speak PHP. Every page can have a custom background image. No built-in WYSIWYG editor, so text and layout possibilities are very limited - although I find that is often a good thing.

It doesn't come with a built-in music and video playing facility out of the box, which is the biggest minus. The project's forum, however,  shows some successful examples of people who managed to build that in. I can't make any estimate on how hard that would be.

Other than that, it does everything you need. The design is customizable through style sheets and page templates; there are various gallery functions; it's self-hosted, and Open Source (but asks for a backlink to be put somewhere on the site).

Answer (score 0):

- [Drupal](http://drupal.org/)
- [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/)
- [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/)

Google Search Results:

- [Play a MP3 / Wordpress plugin](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=wordpress+mp3+player&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)
- [Photo Gallery / Wordpress Plugin](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=wordpress+photo&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)
- [Videos / Wordpress Plugin](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=wordpress+videos&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

if you need to find Drupal or Joomla plugins, replace tghe word 'Wordpress' in the Google Search

All three of these are very customisable

Comment: I don't see why this got down-voted... All of those, and especially Drupal are very flexible and can easily meet the askers requirements.

Comment: @Radu: "If you answer with a more generic CMS (i.e. WordPress), could you point out some extensions that would be helpful.". From my question, it's pretty explicit that I'm looking for more than a generic CMS. In fact, I already mentioned WordPress as part of my question.

Comment: @Olivier what you are looking for is a configurable CMS with plugin ability to add the desired functionality. I understand you think by asking someone else to do a Google Search for you to find something that only you know what you're looking for is a question about coding. It's not, it's a question about design and personal opinion. I gave the 3 examples of what CMS's are easily configurable

Comment: I would recommend everyone to stay away from Joomla. And Drupal has a hard learning curve.